# Iterating through a list of lists and replacing one specific character

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, replace

So the current problem is that I have a list of lists, for example:

```
info = [['X','X','X','34,0976','1,34542'],['X','X','X','23,9878','32,65354'], ['X','X','X','1,745645','5,76454']]
```

The 'X' are values that I am **NOT** interested in. However, I am trying to replace the commas in the numbers to a decimal point as they are latitude and longitude numbers that I will need to convert into a floating point later on.

My current solution is... well, crap to say the least, but here is my beginners attempt:

```
for lst in defib_info:
    for item in lst:
        for char in item:
            if char == ",":
                char.replace(",",".")
```

I have inserted print() statements in each loop to check if it is entering the necessary amount of times, which it is, but the commas are not being replaced.

I am sure python has a WWWAAAAAYYYYY easier way of doing this so that would be my first question and my second question is why doesn't my code work albeit lacks in performance and aesthetic? Is it because I am trying to modify a list which is immutable?

Any info would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: A list (array) in Python is mutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple list comprehension will work here:

```
info = [['X','X','X','34,0976','1,34542'],['X','X','X','23,9878','36,65354'],['X','X','X','1,745645','5,76454']]

info = [[x.replace(',', '.') for x in i] for i in info]
print(info)
```

Output:

```
[['X', 'X', 'X', '34.0976', '1.34542'], ['X', 'X', 'X', '23.9878', '36.65354'], ['X', 'X', 'X', '1.745645', '5.76454']]
```

Comment: Thank you! I had literally just figured it out maybe about 5 minutes ago! Thank you so much for your input though. Now I won't forget how to do this. haha

Answer (score 0):

Since others had already answered your first question excellently, here is why your solution didn't work (second question):

```
for lst in info:
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        if item != 'X':                            # 1
            lst[i] = item.replace(',', '.')        # 2
```

1. You didn't anticipate the case to ignore 'X'
2. You didn't use `string.replace` and reassign it to `lst[i]` (`i` being the index)

Answer (score 0):

Those are good answers , I just tried with lambda for fun :

```
info = [['X','X','X','34,0976','1,34542'],['X','X','X','23,9878','32,65354'], ['X','X','X','1,745645','5,76454']]

print(list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda y:y.replace(',','.'),x)),info)))
```

output:

```
[['X', 'X', 'X', '34.0976', '1.34542'], ['X', 'X', 'X', '23.9878', '32.65354'], ['X', 'X', 'X', '1.745645', '5.76454']]
```